# SimpleDateFormat RegEx formats

Tags: java, android, regex

Regex master needed!

I have an variable timestamp coming from the server and I need to find which format is used everytime. I've tried implementing a regex formats but they don't work. I'm fairly new to regex patterns but still I've tried working them up my self or else look for a specific example but couldn't find so I'm asking you.

The formats from the server can look like this:

"2015-02-23 15:27:31 UTC"

or

"2015-01-22T19:38:40Z"

here is the code to find the formats:

```
private static String getFormat(String time) {
    String firstRegEx = "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\'T+\'\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\'Z\'$";
    String secondRegEx = "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s\\w{3}$";

    if (time.toLowerCase().matches(firstRegEx)) {
        return firstRegEx;
    } else if (time.toLowerCase().matches(secondRegEx)) {
        return secondRegEx;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Can you look at my regex patterns and tell me what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this? Why don't you just try to parse the string with `SimpleDateFormat`? It's going to be very hard to express decent validation for February 29th using regular expressions, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet totally agreed with you

Comment: checking only the date formats with regex won't create any problem. But date validation using regex must create a major problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you explain more about this issue please?
I cannot just parse this cause it will throw an exception if the format is wrong

Comment: I'm only testing which format is used. Not validating a particular date

Comment: It will only throw an exception if you call the overload that *does* throw an exception. You can call `DateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)` which *won't* throw an exception on failure. And why would you want to know the format but not parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to remove the single quotes arround the char `T`and `Z`and second you call `toLowercase()` wich will canvert `T` to `t` and `Z` to `z`. remove it:

```
private static String getFormat(String time) {
    String firstRegEx = "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z$";
    String secondRegEx = "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s\\w{3}$";

    if (time.matches(firstRegEx)) {
        return firstRegEx;
    } else if (time.toLowerCase().matches(secondRegEx)) {
        return secondRegEx;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z$
```

Your first regex should be simply this.This will match `2015-01-22T19:38:40Z`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/aI4rA5/4

Your second regex works fine.

Comment: Wow what an awesome tool!
Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the alternative solution suggested in the comments...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getFormat("2015-02-23 15:27:31 UTC"));
    System.out.println(getFormat("2015-01-22T19:38:40Z"));
}

private static DateFormat getFormat(String time) {
    DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"); 
    DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    if (isFormat(format1, time)) {
        return format1;
    } else if (isFormat(format2, time)) {
        return format2;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private static boolean isFormat(DateFormat format, String candidate) {
    return format.parse(candidate, new ParsePosition(0)) != null;
}
```

If you were using the regex to decide how to parse later on you could bundle this into a single method capable of consuming multiple formats...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDate("2015-02-23 15:27:31 UTC"));
    System.out.println(getDate("2015-01-22T19:38:40Z"));
}

private static Date getDate(String time) {
    DateFormat[] formats = { new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"), 
                             new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z") };
    Date date = null;
    for (DateFormat format : formats) {
        if ((date = format.parse(time, new ParsePosition(0))) != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: thank you I already got the answer from Jens working but appreciate the help

Comment: You don't need to use the overload which throws an exception - you can call the overload which takes a `ParsePosition` parameter - that won't throw.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only possible formats then it is enough to test if date.charAt(10) == 'T'